# How to use python module on windows command prompt

Tags: python

I run this module on python shell,

```
*encoder.py*

import base64

def str_to_base64(x):
    return base64.b64encode(x.encode('utf-8'))

print(str_to_base64('python'))
```

I could get answer, this

```
b'Hl0aG9u'
```

but,I tryed to run it on windows command prompt,

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1198]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files>
C:\Program Files>python3 encoder.py
Python
```

the answer is wrong, I want to get correct results like python shell.
please teach me a best solution.

Comment: It's working fine for me?

Comment: You put `encoder.py` under `C:\Program Files` ?

Comment: It worked fine on python shell only. If I use windows command, I could'nt get.

Comment: I put like `C:\Program Files>python3 encoder.py` on windows command,But it does'nt work, I could get `python`,. This result is not encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this official documentation https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html

Comment: my problem was that I didn't understand Current directory. And then I tried to run `encoder.py`. As a results, it does'nt work. So I read the documentation(Thank you so much) after that, I changed Current directory like this `C:\Program Files\python39`. And then  I tried to put like this `C:\Program Files\python39>py encoder.py`. Finally I got the correct results `b'Hl0aG9u`. Thank you for your advice.